# java script open links in new tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

An html example is :

```
<div id="box_5999439903" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm">

    <a href="profile.45233.html">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="box_5447207448" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_5419085632" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_7266696625" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_5832298219" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_7204247411" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_33341775" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_5693580" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_6737088823" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
<div id="box_5997535946" class="peoplegrid-box mrm mbm"> … </div>
```

i have 10 div ! each one contain a  href="profile.45233.html"!
how to open every link in a new tab with a specified  prefix="www.google.com/" ?:
in my example if "href="profile.45233.html""   the link to open will be "www.google.com/profile.45233.html""

Comment: You want to open all these links in a new tab at once?

Comment: yes Bill with the an added prefix

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, you want each link in its own tab, IE, 10 links, 10 tabs, or you want 1 new tab, which contains all 10 links in it?

Comment: each link on a tab :) really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

add the `target='_blank'` attribute to each anchor, like this

```
<a href="/profile.html?view=mini&uid=5999439903&src=obr" target='_blank'>
```

that will make it open in a new tab

Comment: Yes, but that's not W3C compliant for XHTML Strict DOCTYPEs. Then use `open()`.

Comment: how so? could you please cite a doc which states that?

Comment: thanks. hmm. stupid standards. so off topic but, how would you enable an ajax file upload in a browser which does not support javascript `FormData()`, since AFAIK the only way to do so is by targetting a hidden iframe? If you can't answer here maybe I'll start a new question for that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FormData Object, since it's not a W3C recommendation, yet?

Comment: So, FormData is not a recommendation, and target is not W3C compliant. So, ajax uploading is currently very possible, just not at all within W3C spec. So at this point in time I would say I have no interest in being W3C compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just open up 10 tabs on a user. Also, you can't guarantee a link being clicked will open in a new tab so you're probably spinning your wheels trying to force it.

You can use `target="_blank"` to recommend a link open in a new tab/window (it's up to the user) or if you want to go the Javascript route so you can add your prefix to the url you can do:

```
var link_prefix = 'http://www.google.com';
$('.peoplegrid-box a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open( link_prefix + this.href);
});
```